# Sorting an array of structs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sorting, struct

I have an array of structs called leaders.  The struct class looks like this, for contextual info:

```
class Leader < Struct.new(:rank, :user); end
```

Two questions:

1. How do I sort the array of structs by rank?
2. How do I sort the array of structs by rank and by user.created_at?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.

Assuming rank is numeric:

```
array.sort {| a, b | a[:rank] <=> b[:rank] }
```

This is just specifying that we compare a and b using `[:rank]`.

2.

```
array.sort {| a, b | a[:rank] == b[:rank] ? 
    a[:user].created_at <=> b[:user].created_at : 
    a[:rank] <=> b[:rank] }
```

This uses a ternary.  If the ranks are equal, we compare by [:user].created_at.  Otherwise, we compare by the ranks.

You could implement <=> in your own class to allow sorting natively:

```
class Leader < Struct.new(:rank, :user)
  def <=>(other)
    self[:rank] <=> other[:rank]
  end
end
```

Then you can do:

```
leaders.sort()
```

If you include [Comparable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Comparable.html), it will provide the other comparison operators too.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an implementation using [sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003120).  As noted in the documentation, it may be less efficient than a version using sort, depending on how expensive it is to retrieve the `rank` and `created_at` values.

Sorting by rank:

```
leaders.sort_by {|l| l.rank}
```

Sorting by rank and created_at:

```
leaders.sort_by {|l| [l.rank, l.user.created_at]}
```